# No X509TrustManager implementation available htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

For some reason my code with everything imported correctly, using Htmlunit causes an error.

```
package htmlunittesting;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlDivision;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class httpunittest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://blockchain.info/address/17iyEdbcG3G6RrDHYsi2MzG6RY8vRYvjXm");
    final HtmlDivision div = page.getHtmlElementById("final_balance");
   // final HtmlAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByName("anchor_name");

    System.out.println(div);

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
}
```

My error is:

```
 Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
at sun.security.ssl.DummyX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 27 more
```

All I want to do is print out what the final balance is on this test wallet.

Entire StackTrace as requested:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:275)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:254)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:155)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:117)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:178)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1313)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1230)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:338)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:407)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:392)
at htmlunittet.httpunittest.main(httpunittest.java:12)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
at sun.security.ssl.DummyX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 27 more
```

And yes that is all my code, no other classes.

Comment: All i want you to do is post the entire stack trace and the code that actually threw it.

Answer (score 4):

You should add these parameters to java virtual machine:

```
        System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "../path/yourtruststore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "yourpasswordfortruststore");
```

If you need Mutual Authentication:

```
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","../path../yourkeystore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","yourpasswordforkeystore");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
```