# No X509TrustManager Implementation available

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl

I am invoking an AWS API, I keep running into following error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:709)
       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:449)
       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:411)
       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:360)
       at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.doInvoke(AWSKMSClient.java:2723)
       at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.invoke(AWSKMSClient.java:2693)
       at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.generateDataKey(AWSKMSClient.java:1488)
       at com.infor.aws.KMSTest.createDEK(KMSTest.java:217)
       at com.infor.aws.KMSTest.main(KMSTest.java:144)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
       at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
       at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
       at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
       at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:132)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
       at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy2.connect(Unknown Source)
       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
       at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
       at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:854)
       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
       ... 8 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X509TrustManager implementation available
       at sun.security.ssl.DummyX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1119)
       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
       ... 35 more
```

I have gone through multiple threads here on Stackoverflow and added all the required truststore, truststoretype system properties. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856560/no-x509trustmanager-implementation-available-htmlunit) I have tried. But nothing is working. Has anyone come across this ? I am invoking it like below

```
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                                   .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

KeyStore ks  = KeyStore.getInstance("BCFKS");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("<jre-home>\\\\lib\\\\security\\\\cacerts"), "changeit".toCharArray());
tmf.init(ks);

 // Get hold of the trust manager
X509TrustManager x509Tm = null;
for (TrustManager tm : tmf.getTrustManagers()) {
     if (tm instanceof X509TrustManager) {
          x509Tm = (X509TrustManager) tm;
          break;
     }
}
```

Comment: You are invoking it how?

Comment: BCFKS for bouncy castle? If you want to use default type of ks,`KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());`

Comment: Yes BCFKS for bouncy castle

Comment: Try to print all the trust managers and see if you have more than one. The first one seems to be `DummyX509TrustManager`.

Comment: Did you try to set provider to Security if it is null? And if it is null, then  `Security.addProvider(new YourProvider());`?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can you share me your updated AWS S3 client creation code on my email id (er.rahulmunjal@gmail.com) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved when we moved the AWS-client initialization to a place after setting the trust store password. In my code, I was creating AWS-Client too early.

Answer (score 4):

After debuggging for several hours, it turned out to be a corrupted keystore in my case. Check if you can list the contents of the keystore using the keytool command.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was invoking a SOAP service that needed SSL authentication before my truststore was built. So the service call didn't have a certificate or at least a fully formed one and that caused the service invocation to fail with this error.

When I moved the spring initialization first, then trust store building, and finally service call, that fixed it. To create a certificate, you can do the following:

```
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
trustStore.load(null, null);
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

FileInputStream fis = null;
FileOutputStream fos = null;

fis = new FileInputStream(<your cert file>);
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(fis);
fis.close();

trustStore.setCertificateEntry(<cert name/alias>, certificate);
fos = new FileOutputStream(<path of the file to write to>);
// "changeit" is the default password that is used.
trustStore.store(fos, "changeit".toCharArray());
fos.close();
```

If it is PKCS12 that you want, replace it in the place of JKS.