# Unable to download large files via allowing insecure urls using scala/java

Tags: scala, scalaj-http

I am trying to download large files from internet using insecure urls bypass. But its throwing error.

```
No X509TrustManager implementation available
```

This is what I tried

```
    val trustAllCerts = Array[TrustManager] {
  new TrustManager() {
    def getAcceptedIssuers: Array[X509Certificate] = null

    def checkClientTrusted(certs: Array[X509Certificate], authType: String): Unit = {}

    def checkServerTrusted(certs: Array[X509Certificate], authType: String): Unit = {}
  }
}



// Install the all-trusting trust manager
try {
  val sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
  sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom {})
  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory)
} catch {
  case e: Exception =>

}


    val connection = new URL(downloadUrl).openConnection().asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", s"Basic ${encodeCredentials(username, password)}")
    val responseCode = connection.getResponseCode

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
      val inputStream = connection.getInputStream
      val fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\sd\\Downloads\\somefile.csv.gz")

      val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
      var bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)
      while (bytesRead != -1) {
        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
        bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)
      }

      fileOutputStream.close()
      inputStream.close()

      println("File downloaded successfully.")
    } else {
      println(s"Error: HTTP response code $responseCode")
    }

    connection.disconnect()
```

I have also tried using scalaj-http. Here I can bypass the urls but not able to download huge files. Its throwing java heap space error.

```
                val resp = Http(downloadUrl)
                          .option(HttpOptions.allowUnsafeSSL)
                          .option(HttpOptions.connTimeout(10000))
                          .option(HttpOptions.readTimeout(25000))
                         .auth(username, password).asString
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No X509TrustManager implementation available htmlunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856560/no-x509trustmanager-implementation-available-htmlunit)